# type deduction from virtual member function ptr (bug?)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is an example of subtle bug that was very difficult to find, caused by a non intuitive type deduction. The programmer expected "var2" to be of type "derived2" from the template argument type deduction in the NewValue() function. What actually happens is the deduced type for var2 is the 
base class "derived1". If you have an over-ride of the ConvertValue() virtual function in the derived class then this compiles and works as expected.

I put in the compiler breaker line just to demonstrate the type mismatch. The issue is that NewValue<> is used in many places where the unexpected type deduction passes cleanly giving unexpected results. 
Also, the programmer expected to be able to just inherit the base class member function "ConvertValue()" without having to to over-load it in every derived class just to get NewValue<> to work as expected.

Is this being interpreted correctly by the compiler or is it a compiler bug?

```
class base 
{
    int x;

public:

    base() : x(10){}
    int value() const { return x; }
    void value( int val ) { x = val; }
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    virtual void ConvertValue( int x) { value( Factor()*x); }
    virtual int Factor() const { return 2; }

};

class derived2 : public derived1
{
public:
    //virtual void ConvertValue( int x) { value( Factor()*x); }
    virtual int Factor() const { return 3; }

};

template<typename T>
T NewValue( void (T::*unitsFunc)(int), int value)
{
    T obj;
    (obj.*unitsFunc)(value);
    return obj;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto var1 = NewValue( &derived1::ConvertValue, 10 );
    auto var2 = NewValue( &derived2::ConvertValue, 10 );

    std::cout   << "Test type deduction from virtual member function" << std::endl << std::endl 
                << "This should have value of 20:   " << var1.value()  << std::endl 
                << "This should have value of 30:   " << var2.value()  << std::endl 
                << (var2.value() == 30 ? "CORRECT" : "INCORRECT - bad type deduction") << std::endl << std::endl ;

    // this will not compile because NewValue<>() is returning type "derived1" instead of "derived2" 
    derived2 test = NewValue( &derived2::ConvertValue, 10 );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. Whenever you apply `&` to `&derived2::ConvertValue` the result is always a pointer to member of the class where `ConvertValue` is declared. This means the type from the result of `&derived2::ConvertValue` is `void (derived1::*)(int)`. (This is also the reason why when you override it in `derived2`, the code compiles)

However, any pointer to member function of a base class can be converted to a pointer to member of a derived class. This is because all instances of `derived2` have a member function of `derived1::ConvertValue` that they inherit. Therefore, you can explicitly tell the compiler to convert it as such:

```
auto var2 = NewValue<derived2>( &derived2::ConvertValue, 10 );
```

Comment: yeah, thought so. I was hoping that the power of type deduction could be used to keep the syntax clean. I will have to ponder some alternative because this stuff is used everywhere in a large code base.  Thanks